# Line numbers not showing with pygments in Asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using pygments as code highlighter in Asciidoctor. I have code in Javascript, but for some strange reason the line number is not showing.

I have it configured as follows:

```
:source-highlighter: pygments
```

and then add the code as follows:

```
[source,typescript,linenums]
[subs="verbatim,attributes"]
----
include::../src/chapter1/example2.ts[tags=tag1,indent=0]
----
```

The code gets highlighted alright, but the line numbers are not showing. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the example a try and it worked for me with the following setup:

- Asciidoctor 2.0.15
- ruby 2.6.6p146
- Gem pygments.rb installed (it will not be installed by default)
- Python installed ([AFAIK it is a requirement for pygments to work](https://sachingpta.gitlab.io/_posts/jekyll-pygments-rouge.html))

In case you're using AsciidoctorJ, I found that pygments.rb is not pre-bundled in the JAR. I would recommend to switch to `rouge` instead, as it is 100% Ruby and pre-bundled with AsciidoctorJ.